# Facebook connect button language change

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I use the Facebook toolkit on my web site. My [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) button seems to be in English, but I want to show it in Turkish. How can I change it to Turkish?

Address: http://www.lipres.com/UyeGiris.aspx

Comment: There is somewhere the line `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`, isn't it? Try to replace `en_US` with the country code of Turkey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use JS-SDK with your locale ([full list of locales supported](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)):

```
//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js
```

For more info see Localization section in [JS-SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You may also wish to read [Internationalization guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/) for translation of other parts of your application...